# Directional Derivative defines Descent Direction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a proper convex function that is not necessarily differentiable and let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\mathbf{0} \notin \partial f(x)$. **I want to prove that if $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that the directional derivative $f^\prime (x;v) < 0$ then $v$ is a descent direction of $f$ at $x$**

**How my proof starts:** Suppose $f(x;v) <0$. Then, by convexity, we have the Taylor-like expansion $$\forall t >0: f(x + tv) \geq f(x) + f^\prime(x;tv) = f(x) + t f^\prime (x;v)$$ Rearranging terms, we have $$\frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} \geq f^\prime (x; v)$$ For ease of notation, let $\Delta_t f(x;v) := \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t}$. Then, continuing from the above expression, we have that $$\Delta_t f(x;v) \geq f^\prime (x;v) = \inf_{t>0} \Delta_t f(x;v)$$ where equality of the rightmost expression follows by convexity.

**Where my proof gets shaky:** Let $t^\star \in \arg\inf_{t>0} \Delta_t f(x;v)$. Then, $$\exists \varepsilon \in (0,t^\star), \forall \alpha \in [t^\star-\epsilon, t^\star + \epsilon]: \Delta_\alpha f(x;v) < 0 \implies f(x+\alpha v) < f(x)$$ which therefore means that $v$ is in fact a descent direction.

**The flaws of my proof:**

1. The infimum is over an open set so there's no guarantee that  $\arg\inf_{t>0} \Delta_t f(x;v)$ is non-empty.
2. Assuming $t^\star$ does exist, my proof then depends on the fact that the difference quotient $\Delta_t f(x;v)$ is continuous in $t$ about $t^\star$, allowing me to construct a ball $[t^\star - \epsilon, t^\star + \epsilon]$. This also may not be true.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, everything is a bit simpler.
By the definition of the directional derivative we have:
$$0>f'(x;v) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t} =\inf_{t>0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t},$$
where the latter equality holds due to the convexity of $f$.
Now by the definition of $\inf$ we got that for $t$ small enough
$$f(x+tv)-f(x)\leq 0,$$
which means that $v$ is the descent direction of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: I'm almost there, would be great if you could say a little more about the "definition of inf" part. What property of inf allows one to make the statement "for $t$ small enough?"

Comment: Okay, I got it now: We need the definition of limit (not infimum), which from definition 4.1 in Baby Rudin, states the following: $\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q$ if $q$ is such that $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0: d(x,p) < \delta \implies d(f(x),q) < \epsilon$$

Can't believe I forgot that...

Comment: I'm not sure that using just $\lim$ you can prove it. The only thing you can show in the above comment is $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0\colon |t|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}|<\epsilon,$$ from which you cannot simply conclude that $f(x+tv)\leq f(x)$. Instead, from $\inf_{t>0} \Delta_t<0$ simply follows that $$\exists \delta>0\colon t \in (0,\delta) \Rightarrow \Delta_t \leq 0.$$

Comment: I don't think you got the limit argument I was making since it should be $|\Delta_t - f^\prime (x;v)| < \epsilon$  as oppoosed to $|\Delta_t | < \epsilon$ as you wrote. However, after reading this http://mathonline.wikidot.com/epsilon-definition-of-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-bounded I now see how one can also use infimum to prove this. Thanks a lot!